# Why are UIImage's partially loaded in the TableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a table view. First, I load text data for all cells from database. Next, I load image for every cell from another database. But when I tried to set images, they are not displayed.

If I use

```
let cell = myTableView.dataSource?.tableView(myTableView,
                                       cellForRowAt: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell
```

then images loaded only in invisible cells. It means that those cells that I see the very first (before scrolling down) don't show their images. But all others do.

Another way, if I use

```
let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell
```

then the opposite happens - only those cells that I see show their images, but all others don't.

After that I do

```
cell.setImage(image: image)
```

```
func setImage(image: UIImage) {
        guard let myImageView = myImageView else { return }
        myImageView.image = image
    }
```

I set images not in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {...}` because as I said, images come after creating cells.

Comment: you can use reloadData after getting images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the Table View in the main thread after the load. You can do it with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.yourTableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: yes, you're right. I did it only after setting text data and didn't after receiving images